# Privileges, Timing, and Beta

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Last night, I broke 500 reputation and according to the system earned the right to [Cast Close and Reopen Votes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (I even did it once, just to make sure it really was working). However, on other sites this is a privilege at 3,000.

I know Beta privilege levels are lower, but WB.se is out of beta. Was this value mistakenly unchanged, or do those changes not take place until we get skinned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi and congratulations on making the 500 reputation mark.

Worldbuilding is in the transition between beta and graduated site. As such we have now elected moderators, ads like graduated sites, but while the theme is in preparation, we don't get to the graduated reputation scale. That's the last element to happen.

We don't know yet when this will be done, but it might be any day. It might still give you enough time to reach the 3,000 mark :-)

Comment: I heard a rumor that they push the release back a month every time the topic comes up.

Comment: @Frostfyre just like valve does with half life 3...

Comment: @Frostfyre If that's true, I think that's very immature. I don't think I'd stick around much if I found that higher-ups handled themselves like that. I come here to avoid toxicity of that nature.

Comment: @TheAnathema, I'm pretty sure that's a joke. :-)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin If so, it went way over my head, but elsewhere on the internet I've had bad experiences, hence my reaction. It happens quite frequently. I sure hope no one on here has powertrips like that.

Comment: @TheAnathema Yeah, that was a joke I saw in one of the chat rooms.

Comment: Actually, it's [six to eight weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/300663#19514).

Comment: @PeregrineRook It's perpetually six to eight weeks.

Comment: I remember hearing way back that SE wanted site graduations to be atomic (beta to graduation without intermediate steps). Did they change their mind?